# Digitally sign pdf in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I would like your advice since I am a while now stuck on this.
I am trying to digitally sign a pdf from my .NET application. I have found many examples and libraries that do this by importing the file and a pfx file containing the certificate.

My situation is somehow different because I am using an API that provides me the document signature (the signature of the hash of the document) like this:

`"ZFHl/+5jhJX .... 82Y9pA=="`

It also provides me the signer's certificate like this:

```
{
    "Issuer": "CN=(Test) CA 001, OU=LIT-PKI, OID.3.1504.9=VAT-XXXXXX, O=XXX, C=EN",
    "Subject": "CN=XXX XXXX, SERIALNUMBER=X-XXXXX, G=XXXXX, SN=XXXXX, C=EN",
    "NotBefore": "2023-04-28T11:49:00+03:00",
    "NotAfter": "2023-12-31T11:49:00+02:00",
    "SerialNumber": "3750DF0D22025202",
    "Thumbprint": "8043A3516E1F6C246643E6D064AB0C8BC39675E4",
    "Certificates": [
        "MIIIj ... 19UrA==",
        "MIIGU ... Oiw==",
        "MIIFpz ... 1aY4="
    ] }
```

Can you help me by giving some advice?
I can't understand how to use this raw values because every resource I see uses a pfx file for the certificate.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Please look at the `Certificates` array, it contains three strings each of which is base64 encoded. Most likely each entry is a base64 encoded certificate. Maybe the actual signer certificate is the first one and the other two build its certificate path. The `Subject` string or the `Issuer` string in combination with the `SerialNumber` value allow you to identify the signer certificate among them for sure.